# how to open result in new tab with autocomplete search jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, autocomplete

below is a code to search in my menu pages it's working fine but missing some options .. if you can help please:

1- i need to highlight the letters what i'm typing which matching the search result with special color.
2- need to allow open the result with mouse right click and open it in new tab as link.
3- when click on result i need to get the result name instead of it's own link in the search text input.

here is my code:

```js
$(function () {
            var menuPages = $('#main-menu li a:has(.childtitle)').map(function () {
                return {
                    label: $(this).text(),
                    value: $(this).attr('href')
                };
            }).toArray();
            $("#txt_MenuSearch").autocomplete({
                source: menuPages,
                select: function (event, target) {
                    var link = target.item.value;
                    window.open(link);
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt_MenuSearch" class="search-input" placeholder="Search here.." />

    <ul id="main-menu">   
        <li class="has-sub"><a href="javascript:;"><span class="title">Menu Header1</span></a>
           <ul>
              <li><a href="yahoo.com"><span class="childtitle">brand one</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="gmail.com"><span class="childtitle">brand two</span></a></li>
           </ul> 
     </li>
    
        <li class="has-sub"><a href="javascript:;"><span class="title">Menu Header2</span></a>
           <ul>
              <li><a href="bmw.com"><span class="childtitle">Car BMW</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="toyota.com"><span class="childtitle">Car Toyota</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="opel.com"><span class="childtitle">Car Opel</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="kia.com"><span class="childtitle">Car Kia</span></a></li>
           </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - For highlighting, use regular expressions to replace the matching text for all shown list items within the autocomplete's _renderItem API function.

2 - For right-clicking and showing context menu, just wrap each match with anchor tags.

3 - For injecting label text instead of link/value into the search field, update your "search" and "focus" events so that they are setting the search input's value as the label text rather than value.

Here's a sample:

```
var menuPages = $('#main-menu li a:has(.childtitle)').map(function () {
                return {
                    label: $(this).text(),
                    value: $(this).attr('href')
                };
            }).toArray();
            $("#txt_MenuSearch").autocomplete({
                source: menuPages,
                select: function (event, target) {
                    /* On select, show item's label in text input */
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $("#txt_MenuSearch").val(target.item.label); 
                },
                focus: function(event, ui) {
                    /* On focus, show item's label in text input */
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $("#txt_MenuSearch").val(ui.item.label);
                }
            });

            /* Highlight text and handling right-clicking context menu */
            $("#txt_MenuSearch").data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {

                var newText = String(item.label).replace(
                                new RegExp(this.term, "gi"),
                                "<span class='ui-state-highlight'>$&</span>");

                /* Wrapping the matching option within anchor tags */
                newText = '<a href="'+item.value+'">'+newText+'</a>';

                return $( "<li>" )
                .attr( "data-value", item.value )
                .append( newText )
                .appendTo( ul );
            };
```

Comment: thnx @Kevin very much, you solved 2 point for me perfect, but the third one may be you didn't got my point about right clicking on the result,, for clearing this one the all i need to do is to be able to right click on the result and can open it in "open in new tab" as any general link .. i hope you got my point now :)

Comment: @MuhammadS.Eltyar very sorry for the misunderstanding. I've just updated the code in my answer above. All you need to do is: during _renderItem function call, each matching result will need to be wrapped in anchor tags.